# Android VideoView hides Layout Elements

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-videoview

I have the following layout (cut down to a minimal example)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/free_text_default_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/free_text_padding"
        android:text="background element is a video view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, that if I move the EditText around (it has a drag listener attached to it), it dissapears at a certain point of the screen as you can see in this screenshot.

[image]

The problem seems to only appear when I have a VideoView. Even if I don't show a video.
When I replace it with e.g. an ImageView there is no problem at all.

So my question is, what's happening and how can I resolve this?

Thanks for your time!

UPDATE 1: This only happens if the VideoView has

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

when I set it to some "dp" value everything works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution to my question jet but I have found a workaround:
Once the layout is finished, I get the height from the parent container, subtract 1px and set this as new height for the video view.
The 1px is barely visible...

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = videoView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = parentView.getHeight() - 1;
    videoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```